How can I break the feedback loop network and add loading effect
Here is the circuit schematic.

Consider Loading effect in feedback and break the loop.

Simplify the circuit.

$$A_{v,open} = \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = -\frac{g_{m1} R_F R_D} {R_S  +R_F}$$
Calculate \$\beta\$ in two port feedback network.

$$
\beta = g_{21}=\frac{V_2}{V_1} |_{I_2 = 0} = 1
$$
$$\Rightarrow LG = A_{v,open} \beta =  -\frac{g_{m1} R_F R_D} {R_S  +R_F}$$

Didn't the author already do this in Figure 8.63?

@internet Yeah, He replaced the source voltage with Norton equivalent current source.  I wan t to know if  it is possible to analyse this circuit with loading effect  without using Norton?

if you don't like Norton just keep it like that and do exactly the same.

@internetI am confused.  Is my analysis here correct? What is the same?

@internet I am confused. I think I already did analysis in this post as you suggested . Is my analysis here correct?

no, this is voltage-current feedback and your break loop is wrong.

@internet Do you mean the book's Norton equivalent current source. is only method.

The given expression for LG cannot be correct. This is because , for example, for Rs=0 the loop gain LG must be zero. Another example: For RF appoaching infinity, the loop gain must be zero. However, for this case the given expression  will be a finite value.

In case we open the loop at the gate there will be no (remarkable) loading effect.

In this case, the open-loop gain (between gate and drain node with Vin=0) will be
$$A_{open}=-g_m [R_D \parallel(R_F +R_S)] $$
Hence, the gain between the gate and the node between Rs and Rf (the loop gain LG) is
$$LG =-\frac{R_S} {R_S + R_F} A_{open} = -g_m \frac{R_D R_S} {R_D+R_F+R_S} $$
EDIT: CALCULATION OF THE CLOSED-LOOP GAIN Acl
Comment: In the above calculation the gain Aopen (between gate and drain) is NOT identical to the gain Aol (between the circuits input and drain) which appears in the classical feedback expression and which is part of the loop gain. Hence, it will be calculated in the following.
For this purpose, we realize that the output voltage at the drain node consists of two parts:

1.)
$$V_{out1} = \frac{R_D} {R_D + R_S + R_F} V_{in} \text{(caused directly through $R_S$ and $R_F$)}$$

2.)
$$V_{out2}=-g_m \bigr[R_D \parallel (R_S + R_F)\bigr] V_G \text{(caused by the FETs current source)}$$
with $$V_G =V_{in} \frac{(R_F + R_D)} {(R_D + R_S + R_F)}$$
3.) From this, the gain Aol (open loop without feedback effect) can be found to be
$$A_{ol} =
\frac{(V_{out1} + V_{out2})} {V_{in}} 
=......
= \frac{R_D (1-g_m R_F)} {(R_D + R_S + R_F)}$$
4.) Together with the loop gain LG we can find the closed-loop gain Acl:
$$A_{cl} =\frac{A_{ol}}{(1-LG)}=......= \frac{R_D (1-g_m R_F)} {(R_D+R_S+ R_F +  g_m R_D R_s)}$$

How  do you know $\beta  = \frac{R_s} {(Rs+RF)}$ when the feedback network is composed of $R_F, R_D$?

@ kile - I did not say that this ratio is beta. I was interested in the loop gain only. I have computed the gain between gate and drain (opening at the gate with Vin=0). And - as a second step - the voltage division between Rs and Rf. That`s all. The "distribution" between gain without feedback and beta is another question (another definition depending on the opening point)

Without $\beta$, how can calculate close loop gain? Is there a way for you to calculate close loop gain in your method?

@ kile - why are you asking "without beta"? My "beta" is different from your "beta" - but this is not a problem. This is because I have opened the loop at another node. Thefore, I have another gain without feedback - but I can, of course, use the standard form for the closed-loop gain.

Can you continue your answer on how you calculate close loop gain?

@ kile - the final calculation of the closed-loop gain is not as simple as it perhaps looks. Of course, the classical expression for the closed-loop gain can be used [Acl=Aol/(1+LG)] but we cannot automatically derive the expression for Aol from the loop gain expression (because we only know the product LG=beta*Aol). Hence, some additional calculations resp. considerations are necessary.

continued: Furthermore, it must be taken into account that a portion of the input signal arrives directly at the drain node (though Rs and Rf) without any phase inversion .

I have add diagram to your loop break method. So can you find the close loop gain in this way?

@ kile - please see my edit for the closed-loop gain Acl (and thanks for editing my text)

Which point is $V_{out1}$ and $V_{out2}$ in schematics? Can you mark them in the diagram?

@ kile - in the text, I wrote that Vout at the drain node consists of two parts. To me, this should be clear.

In my opinion, $$\frac{V_{in} - V_{out}} {R_S + R_F} = \frac{V_{in} -V_g} {R_S}$$
$$\Rightarrow V_g = \frac{R_F} {R_S + R_F} V_{in} + \frac{R_S} {R_S + R_F}  V_{out}$$

@ kile - What is Vg and for which purpose (at which step of the calculation) do you need it?

$V_g$ is gate voltage of $M_1$

@kile In my calculation (point 2) I need the gate voltage caused by the FETs current source only.

@ LvW Take a look at at diagrams made by me. Are they compatible with your equations here?
